# How to show that $H \cap Z(G) \neq \{e\}$ when $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ with $\lvert H\rvert>1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

> Let $G$ be a group of order $p^n$, $p$ a prime, $n>1$ and $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$ with $\lvert H\rvert>1$. Show that $H \cap Z(G) \neq \{e\}$.

Answer (score 6):

If you know how to show that a $p$-group has a [non-trivial center](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Orbit-Stabilizer_Theorem), you can approach this problem similarly.

Consider the action of $G$ on itself by conjugation. Since $H$ is normal, it must be the union of some conjugacy classes. Each conjugacy class is either a single element of $Z(G)$ or a subset of $p$-power order $> 1$ (by the [orbit-stabilizer theorem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Orbit-Stabilizer_Theorem)). The order of $H$ is also a $p$-power $> 1$ by the hypothesis. $H$ contains the conjugacy class $\{e\}$. If this were the only conjugacy class consisting of a single element of $Z(G)$ in $H$, we would have $p \mid 1$, a contradiction. It follows that $H \cap Z(G) \ne \{e\}$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Look at the group action of $G$ on $H$ by conjugation.

Comment: @Downvoter: Why?

Comment: This is a right hint. +1

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

> Theorem: Let $H$ is a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$, and let $K$ be a $p$ subgroup of $G$. so if $|H|\not\equiv 1 \pmod p$, then $H\cap C_G(K)\neq 1$.

Comment: $\large\oplus\; \overset{\small\otimes\otimes}{\Large\smile}$

Comment: @amWhy: After watching TV more than 4 hours, my eyes become like that. :^D

Comment: @BabakS. , this is a cool theorem , Is there a name of it so i can search for a proof on internet ? or , Do you know any source provide a proof for it ?

Comment: @MathsLover: You can find it in Rose's book I think. :-)

Comment: @BabakS. , Which chapter ? section ? exploring hall of the book looking up  such theorem seems to be searching for a Cola bottle in Indian ocean :D

Comment: @MathsLover: 5.7, theorem and the next one.