# Prove $N\cap Z(P)\ne e$ given a $p$-group $P$ and a normal subgroup $N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $P$ be a $p$-group and let $N\triangleleft P$. Prove $N\cap Z(P)\ne e$ .

Here's what I know so far: $P$, being a $p$-group, is nilpotent and therefore is solvable. That means that it has its upper central series: $e=Z_0\triangleleft Z_1\triangleleft Z_2....Z_n...$ where $Z_1=Z(P)$ and that at some point, the series stabilizes at P forever... I also know that $Z_{i+1}=${ $x\in P|\forall y\in P: [x,y]\in Z_i$}. (In my notebook it's been defined that way: $Z_{i+1}=\pi^{-1}(Z(G$\ $Z_i)$ whichc confuses me a little. )

How can I show that the desired intersection is not empty?

Comment: Just a minor detail: you want the intersection to be larger than $e$ instead of non empty.

Comment: Thank you.I shall try it that way.

Comment: I have added an answer to the linked question using the upper central series.