# Solution Verification: $\; o(G) = p^n$, $p$ is a prime, and $ N \neq (e) $ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Then $N \cap Z \neq (e)$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

This problem is from *Herstein*:

This method is different - and uglier - than what has been described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438005/how-to-show-that-h-cap-zg-neq-e-when-h-is-a-normal-subgroup-of-g-w). I did not understand the solution given there at first but after writing the one below, I get it. But I posted this here to get this one verified - to get some consolation. So would really appreciate it if someone kind 
enough could read through the clutter to check if it is right. Thanks in advance.

> If  $\; o(G)  = p^n$, where $p$ is a prime, and if $ N \neq (e) $ is a
>   normal subgroup of $G$, prove that $N \cap Z \neq (e)$, where $ Z $ is
>   the centre of $G$.

*My Attempt:*

$ (N\vartriangleleft  G$ stands for $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G)$

We use induction on the order of $G$. The base case is vacuously true. We could also use induction on $ n $ where $o(G) = p^n$, for a given prime $p$, but again the base case ($n = 1$)  is true since $N \neq (e) \implies N = Z = G $ since $G$ is a cyclic group of prime order. Either way  the remaining arguments are pretty much the same.

Now suppose $ o(G) = p^n $ and $N  \vartriangleleft G$ and $N \neq (e)$. Now, $Z \vartriangleleft G $ and in particular, $ Z \vartriangleleft N $. $ N /Z $ is also a subgroup of $G / Z $. Here, $ N / Z  = \{Zn \ | \ n \in N\}$. We claim, $ N /Z \vartriangleleft  G /Z$, since for each $ g \in G, n \in N,  $ we have $ (Zg)(Zn)(Zg)^{-1} = Z(gng^{-1}) \in N / Z $ since $ gng^{-1} \in N$. We also know that the centre of a group of order $p^n$ is not trivial from the class equation.

Hence we have in our hands a group, $ G / Z $ whose order is $ p^m \  ; \ m \lt n $. And we have a normal subgroup $N/Z$ of it. Now if $ N /Z = (Z) $, the singleton group, then $N \subseteq Z$ and we would be done.  If not, then we can apply an appropriate induction hypothesis.

Take, $\overline Z $ to be the centre of $ G /Z $. Then the induction hypothesis gives us $( N /Z) \cap \overline Z \neq \{Z\} $. That is there is $Zn \in ( N /Z) \cap \overline Z $ and $Zn \neq Z$.

So the deduction from this is that there is an element $n \in N$, $n \not \in Z$ such that $ nxn^{-1}x^{-1} \in Z $ for each $x \in G$. Since $N \vartriangleleft  G$ we have that $  nxn^{-1}x^{-1} =  n(xn^{-1}x^{-1}) \in N $ for each $ x \in G $. Now if $  nxn^{-1}x^{-1} = e $ for each $ x \in G $ then $n \in Z$, which is a contradiction. So there is $x \in G$ such that $  nxn^{-1}x^{-1} \in Z$,  $ \; nxn^{-1}x^{-1}  \in N$ and $  nxn^{-1}x^{-1} \neq e $ which establishes our result.

Comment: Instead of talking about $N/Z$ which seems to induce false reasonings, you should use the projection $\pi$ of $G$ over $G/Z$. Apart from this, it works IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Since $N$ is normal in $G$, it is the union of conjugacy classes of $G$. The noncentral conjugacy classes of $G$ have all size a proper power of $p$ (the noncentral elements of $G$ have centralizer of order strictly less than $p^n$). So:
$$|N|=|N\cap Z(G)|+\sum_{i}p^{\alpha_i}\tag 1$$
where $\alpha_i\ge 1$ for every $i$. But then $p$ divides the LHS of $(1)$ and the sum in the RHS, so $p$ must divide $|N\cap Z(G)|$ as well, which then can not be $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you say that $Z \vartriangleleft N$? We don't know that $Z \leq N$.

Comment: You are right. But $N /Z  = \{Zn \ | \ n \in N\} $ still makes sense.  And the rest is correct too I think. So I should do away with that line.

Comment: Well, that would be $ZN/Z = NZ/Z$, not $N/Z$.